# ReloadSections crash : iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9

---

I have a tableview with expandable/collapsable sections. It works fine in iOS 8 but crashes at reloadSections in iOS 9. This is the code :

`NSRange range = NSMakeRange(selectedSection, 1);
    [_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

I have looked up the issue and it seems some people have encountered it but none of the solutions have yet worked for me. Of course I could reload the table but that won't give me the animated look, and I just don't want the whole tableview to reload. Here is the only log I have (via bt command on console) :

```
thread #1: tid = 0xfecd, 0x25be16aa UIKit__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke + 98, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffc)

frame #0: 0x25be16aa UIKit__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke + 98
frame #1: 0x25d074fc UIKit__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke1011 + 184
frame #2: 0x25be10b4 UIKit-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2348
frame #3: 0x25bc5684 UIKit-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 10648
frame #4: 0x25bc2b5a UIKit-[UITableView _updateSections:updateAction:withRowAnimation:headerFooterOnly:] + 434
frame #5: 0x25bc299e UIKit`-[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] + 38
frame #6: 0x0028d956 MyAPP-[MyView expandCollapseSection:](self=0x16f90170, _cmd=0x0096e193, sender=0x16fec2d0) + 1230 at MyView.m:256
frame #7: 0x25a09770 UIKit-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
frame #8: 0x25a09700 UIKit-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 64
frame #9: 0x259f161e UIKit-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 446
frame #10: 0x25a09050 UIKit-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 616
frame #11: 0x259c2fc6 UIKit_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 10934
frame #12: 0x25a01e10 UIKit-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 904
frame #13: 0x25a015c2 UIKit-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 622
frame #14: 0x259d2118 UIKit-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
frame #15: 0x259d0756 UIKit_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5134
frame #16: 0x217fd256 CoreFoundation__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
frame #17: 0x217fce46 CoreFoundation__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
frame #18: 0x217fb1ae CoreFoundation__CFRunLoopRun + 806
frame #19: 0x2174dbb8 CoreFoundationCFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
frame #20: 0x2174d9ac CoreFoundationCFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
frame #21: 0x229c7af8 GraphicsServicesGSEventRunModal + 160
frame #22: 0x25a39fb4 UIKitUIApplicationMain + 144
frame #23: 0x0009a1ec MyAppmain(argc=1, argv=0x0108bb24) + 108 at main.m:17
```

I have tried using update blocks (beginUpdates) and animation blocks but in vain.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but only with iPhone 6 and only in some sections. It worked with iPhone6 plus. Every device worked with .reloadData() but I wanted a nice animation. When I set the collapsed section number of rows to 1 instead of 0, it also works. The problem has something to do with reloading an empty section in iOS9.
I used this work arround so it was at least a animated update of the tableview. Here the Swift code:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.yourTableView,
                          duration: 0.35,
                          options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations:
    { () -> Void in
        self.forecastTableView.reloadData()
    },
                          completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your section reload statement inside **[self.tableview beginUpdates]** and **[self.tableview endUpdates]:**

```
[self.tableview beginUpdates] 
NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[self.tableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableview endUpdates]
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I have tried this without any success. Sorry I should have mentioned it above.